# Spring cloud contract with XML. Trying to specify mock depend on request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

In the most cases I can specify mock via element content-type and the value inside of it. I'm connecting it with xpath and everything is going well. But now i got a case where inside wsdl every xsd got the same content-type. I have no idea how I can make a condition to specify concrete mock. I guess the only thing which is different in every xsd inside this url is root element. Have u got any solution? Do u think it is possible to specify mock depend on request root element and how ? This is example of my contract

```
Contract.make {
        request {
            priority(1)
            method 'POST'
            url '/ws/xxxx/xxx'
            body(new MatchingStrategy(anyNonEmptyString(), MatchingStrategy.Type.MATCHING))
            bodyMatchers {
                xPath("//*[local-name()='Chnl']/text()", new MatchingTypeValue(MatchingType.EQUALITY, "xxx"))
            }
            headers {
                header(contentType(), regex('application/.*xml.*xxxxxxx.*'))
            }
        }
        response {
            status 200
            body(fileAsBytes("xxxx.xml"))
            headers {
                contentType(applicationXml())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you present some examples that describe the issue? Also your body entry is wrong. Inside the body entry you must have some concrete value. Matching Strategy or MatchingTypeValue shouldn't be used there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding new xpath condition in bodyMatcher for the main xml element.

```
xPath("//*[local-name()='Body']", new MatchingTypeValue(MatchingType.REGEX, ".*nameOfRootXmlElement.*"))
```